# How to fill a complex shape with a white background using Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, vector, svg, image-editing

I'm trying to add a white background to an SVG image [found on the Internet](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Dassault_Rafale.svg). I modified it to only keep one of the shape. It is still a rather complex shape and I didn't manage to achieve what I wanted. I followed several Inkscape tutorials found on the web but none of them worked.

[image: Screenshot of a transparent SVG image depicting a Rafale fighter jet]

Of course I could just add a white rectangle as a background but I'd like to only fill the inside of the shape with white.

How can I do this on Inkscape ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image (after removing **ALL** clipping masks and groupings) was made of black lines. They are not joined together, so there's no closed areas to be filled. I show the construction idea of the image by recoloring a few lines:

[image]

The white fill is possible:

1. Make a copy of the original to the clipboard
2. Select all, apply Path > Stroke to Path; it converts all lines to filled areas with no stroke (takes a long time).
3. Select all, apply Path > Union; you get a complex black shape with holes
4. Select all, apply Path > Break Apart; this separates the interiors of the holes
5. Select all, apply Path > Union; you get one shape which covers the original. It's black:

[image]

6. Change the fill color to white and paste in place the original:

[image]

BTW. I got a PDF when I opened the link you gave. Poppler-Cairo import opened it easily. I removed all groupings by applying Extension > Arrange > Deep Ungroup. This time it hadn't much to do. Some PDFs can have 50 levels of groupings.

Comment: The link to the actual SVG is here: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/09/Dassault_Rafale.svg - I was writing a very similar answer, but you got there first. More or less exactly the same idea ;) +1 from me!

Comment: Thank you. It worked like a charm. What do you mean you've got a PDF with the link I gave ? The Wikimedia Commons link ? Weird, it should redirect to the original SVG image. **Edit:** Oh I see, it's just that I didn't gave the direct link to the SVG but to the Wikimedia Commons page presenting the file.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would take it inside Gimp first, and on a new layer fill the outer spaces with some color, let's say red, and add a third layer of a full white background.
2. I would flatten those two layers and auto trace them inside Inkscape.
3. Delete the red parts and over impose your image in the white object.

---

But the truth is that to have a clean drawing I would just learn how to trace it manually. The shape is pretty simple.

Just add nodes on each intersection and adjust the specific location zooming in.

There are a couple of curved sections. Use a bezier line there.